# Change Owner of MS Flow to other user

Tags: power-automate

In my organization User 1 has created a flow and User 1 has left the organization,

to change the flow owner to other user, I tried Save As option, but its showing the below error,

[image]

also i tried to change owner manually, but its disable, see the below image:

[image]

could anyone please advice how to change the owner of flow to other user.

Answer (score 0):

Please create the duplicate of this flow by using Save as Copy, add new one in a solution and then you will be able to change the Owner. You can do the same without creating a copy (such as your case) also but creating the copy always helps.

Why this is necessary : To change the ownership of a non-solution-aware cloud flow, you must create a new flow with export/import, Save as, or Send a copy. In-place ownership change for non-solution-aware cloud flows isn't available because the owner is part of the flow identity.